# Ansible working with ec2 tags

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook with dynamic ec2 inventory, below is the graph.

```
$ ansible-inventory -i inventory/dynamic_inventory/uat_aws_ec2.yaml --graph
@all:
  |--@aws_ec2:
  |  |--xx.xxx.xx.xx
  |  |--xx.xxx.xx.xx
  |  |--xx.xxx.xx.xx
  |--@nonprod_uat:
  |  |--xx.xxx.xx.3
  |  |--xx.xxx.xx.1
  |  |--xx.xxx.xx.2
  |--@uat_auth:
  |  |--xx.xxx.xx.xx
  |--@uat_web:
  |  |--xx.xxx.xx.xx
  |--@ungrouped:
```

Now if I need to use set_facts for a specific tag?
Example, I need to use something like this.

As I'm already using the plugin for dynamic inventory, it should be simple enough I guess

```
- set_fact:
    deploy: uat
  when:  "ec2_tags/hostgroups('nonprod_uat')"
```

- debug: var=hostvars also gives me the tag information, but need to know how to use it to set_facts on the playbook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer myself after doing some trial and error

- set_fact:
  deploy: uat
  when: hostvars[inventory_hostname].tags.Environment == 'uat'